# Make USB modem work on Puppy Linux 5.28

Tags: modem, puppy-linux, 3g

I have an Alcatel Modem,  when I plug it on my old dell c600 with Puppy Linux.

**This is the log from my Puppy Linux 5.28 on my dell laptop:**

```
tail -f /var/log/messages | grep usb

user.err kernel:usb 1-1: device not accepting address 9, error -71
user.info kernel:usb 1-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 10
```

What can I do to make it work?... It also happends with my opensuse on my laptop but when I  plug it off and in again it "fixex itself".

**This is the log from my OpenSuSe 12.2 on my acer laptop: (to compare)**

```
~ # tailf /var/log/messages | grep usb
Oct 28 13:01:10 acer dbus-daemon[537]: modem-manager[656]: <info>  (Longcheer): GSM modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-1 claimed port ttyUSB1
Oct 28 13:01:10 acer modem-manager[656]: <info>  (Longcheer): GSM modem /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:12.0/usb3/3-1 claimed port ttyUSB1
```

where can I find some info? Can anyone give me a hand?.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] I found [a post with instructions](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/PupDial) - I'm not sure how current that is. It looks like you use Puppy's own Internet Connection Wizard (launched by an icon labeled "connect"), which has an option "Internet by dialup analog or wireless modem". That shows PupDial, which can be used to establish a connection using your modem.

Below is a description about how wireless modems are handled in most Linux distributions (but not all - there are other ways to handle the modems).

I'm not too familiar with Puppy, so I can't give precice instructions, but here is what's going on. You have ModemMnaager running on your system; it's capable of setting up a Mobile Wireless Connection with most USB modems. You probably also have NetworkManager, which interacts with ModemManager to manage that connection. NetworkManager is usually controlled by some GUI interface; the official one is Gnome-based, so I'm not sure if it's included with Puppy, but there should be some graphical tool for settng up network connections on your system, and that will probably show an option for creating a new 3G Wireless connection. Look for that tool.

Comment: I know that wizard... but first puppy should recognize the modem as it is. Will check that post. thanks.

Comment: @maniat1k Yes - from the logs you posted, I can tell that it did recognize it as a GSM modem, so when you PupDial comes up, there should be `ttyUSB1` available for you to use.

Comment: sorry @Shawn second log is about my opensuse recognizing the modem when I plug it the second time... I updated the question

Comment: Got it. Then there are a couple possibilities: check that you have usb_modeswitch and the accompanying definitions to be able to switch your device (if you don't know how, submit another question). If you already have them, try manually modeswitching the modem using it - if that works, you need to add a udev rule to do it automatically. Once that's done, PupDial should see the ttyUSB port.